# Cypress can't load assets from Vite's devserver

Tags: docker, cypress, wsl-2, vite

I have an app running at `http://localhost/` which loads it's assets from a Vite's devserver which is up at `http://localhost:3000/`. Cypress is hitting the main app correctly, but it doesn't load the assets, leaving me with a blank page because the page received no response for the `http://localhost:3000/app.js` file.

Everything works fine if I visit the app directly on the browser. The browser is able to load the assets from port 3000 without problems. They're only failing when requested via the Cypress test runner.

[image]

I tried to `cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')` and it seems like the Vite's devserver is refusing connections. But I checked the Vite documentation to see if there was something that could be blocking this and nothing caught my eyes. Also, the strange part is that they're only blocked when requested via the test runner.

[image]

I'm running Cypress on WSL2 and my app and the Vite devserver are running through Docker mapping to the addresses above. Is there any additional configuration I'm missing?

If I build the assets and serve them from the main app address (`http://localhost/dist/app.js`), everything works fine and my tests run fine. So, I'm guessing there's some sort of configuration I need to do to allow Cypress to request assets form other hosts?

Comment: What happens if you visit `http://localhost:3000`? If I remove the port (local app, no docker) I get an immediate error "failed without a response", so is docker providing a port and if so, should it be 3000?

Comment: Everything works fine if I visit the app directly on the browser. The browser is able to load the assets from port 3000 without problems. They're only failing on Cypress.

Comment: What happens if you `cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')` instead of`cy.visit('http://localhost')`?

Comment: Ok. It seems like Vite's devserver is refusing connections. But I checked the Vite documentation to see if there was something that could be blocking this and nothing caught my eyes. Also, the strange part is that they're only blocked when requested via the test runner.

Comment: It must be something to do with exposed ports on docker (or maybe wsl2). If I run Vue/Vite with script `"dev": "vite"` the app is served on port 3000, and Cypress visits and tests on that port without trouble.

Comment: I though about this, but I can't see a reason why it would hit port 80 and not port 3000. =/

Comment: I suppose you've set up docker correctly?

Comment: Damn... The problem was in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I had exposed VITE's port with `EXPOSE 3000` on the `Dockerfile`, but not in the `ports:` of the `docker-compose.yml`. And since it was working on the browser, I assumed that mapping on the `docker-compose.yml` was redundant. Thanks A LOT for your help, @Fody. REALY appreciate it. It will certainly improve and speedup my development.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be due to Vite by default only accepting requests made using the 'localhost' hostname.

On the other hand, Cypress interprets 'localhost' as '127.0.0.1', so when interpreting `cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')` it actually runs `cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:3000/')`. But Vite won't accept "127.0.0.1".

The best solution I've found is to open your Vite config file (like vite.config.js) and add the following within defineConfig:

```
server: {
  port: 5173,
  host: '127.0.0.1'
}
```

This will make Vite expose the host '127.0.0.1' directly instead of 'localhost', and both 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' will be accepted by the Vite server.

Comment: Thanks! This was my exact problem and saved me a ton of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem was in the `docker-compose.yml` file.
>
> I had exposed VITE's port with `EXPOSE 3000` on the `Dockerfile`, but
> not in the `ports:` of the `docker-compose.yml`.
>
> And since it was working on the browser, I assumed that mapping on the
> `docker-compose.yml` was redundant.

This was originally posted by [Matheus Dal'Pizzol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075162/matheus-dalpizzol) as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324704/cypress-cant-load-assets-from-vites-devserver/77219260#comment127838205_72324704).